# how to add a prototype to an object

Tags: javascript, oop

The following function produces the error '`scoreCounter` is not defined' where it should be defined at that point as a prototype to `Darts`.

```
function Darts() {
    this.Score = 0
    this.x = 1
    this.y = 1
} 

Darts.prototype.scoreCounter = function(x,y) {
(unnecessary code for this quesiton)
}
const test = new Darts()


console.log(test.isPrototypeOf(scoreCounter))
```

how to fix this error(add the prototype correctly)

`scoreCounter` is expected to be part of `test` prototype as the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only defined `Darts.prototype.scoreCounter`, not a variable with a name of `scoreCounter`; thus, the `scoreCounter` method is only visible on the  prototype of `Darts` or on instances of the `Darts` function, i.e. `new Darts().scoreCounter`. To find whether or not a method has been defined on a function's prototype, you can use [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), depending on the situation.

```js
function Darts() {
    this.Score = 0
    this.x = 1
    this.y = 1
} 

Darts.prototype.scoreCounter = function(x,y) {
 //(unnecessary code for this quesiton)
}
const test = new Darts()
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty("scoreCounter"));//false; it's a prototype property
console.log("scoreCounter" in test);
     //true; inherited property found on the prototype chain
console.log(Darts.prototype.hasOwnProperty("scoreCounter"));//true
```

Answer (score 2):

In the console.log statement, you are testing 'scoreCounter', but 'scoreCounter' is not a global variable in your global workspace.

Try this:

```
console.log(Darts.prototype.isPrototypeOf(test))
```

^^^
We just need to check if the prototype/s in 'test' derives from 'Darts' higher up in its prototype chain. This will include any prototype inside of 'Darts' in the search.